# React | Get useEffect to Run Asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am trying to run something in the background while an action is performed.
This is the element that's being updated. It's linked to an object of a user defined class called `spline`. On dragging the point the `spline` object is updated and that in turn updates the curve that you see.

[image]

I am trying to write a function that runs asynchronously in the background whenever `spline` is updated but doesn't hinder anything else, just executes and finishes on its own time. This is the test code I've written.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncer() {

        function wait(ms) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while (end < start + ms) {
                end = new Date().getTime();
            }
        }
        const p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            wait(1000);

            resolve();
        });

        p.then(() => console.log("hello"));
    }

    asyncer();
}, [spline]);
```

But this does hinder the `spline` from being updated in time. Here's what happens.
[image]

The spline doesn't update until the function has completed executing.

Comment: that `wait` is blocking the event loop. you can create a `delay` function using promises

Comment: I'm not sure about the implementation details of your spline and how it's drawn, but it feels to me like your infinite loop that acts as delay(wait) "while (end < start + ms)" is hindering the entire app not just the spline update, maybe you would want to use a (set time out) alternative to add the delay you want.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, javascript is single threaded, and this function

```js
        function wait(ms) {
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while (end < start + ms) {
                end = new Date().getTime();
            }
        }
```

is blocking the event loop. This prevent javascript from executing anything else. What you can do is implement this as a promise instead,

```
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: Sure enough, that worked, but I don't fully see my mistake. I expected the promise to work. I am ultimately trying to put my own code instead of the wait function. That was just supposed to be a test. e.g. let's say I want it to execute some other function that takes a few seconds to execute.

Comment: code executed in a promise doesn't run in a different thread. you may want to look into web workers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would look into them.